# Solve a modular linear system

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I need to know the encryption matrix of the **Hill cipher** given the plain-text "HILLCIPHER" and cipher-text "WLHDMWLHZU"

Let the **encryption matrix** $$A=\begin{pmatrix}x
 & y\\z
 & w
\end{pmatrix}$$

We will split the **plain-text** $$"HI-LL-CI-PH-ER"=(7 \ 8)-(11  \ 11)-(2  \ 8)-(15  \ 7)-(4  \ 17)$$
And the same for the **cipher-text** : $$“WL-HD-MW-LH-ZU”=(22 \  11)-(7 \  3)-(12 \  22)-(11 \  7)-(25 \  20)$$

Using the fact that $"WL" =( "HI" \cdot  \ A) \ mod \ 26$ and that it's the same for **all** the other encrypted letters,
this leads to the system (just using the 2 first pairs):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 (7x+8z) \ mod \ 26 = 22
 & \\ (11x+11z) \ mod \ 26 = 7
\end{pmatrix}$$

But I just can't resolve this.. Any help would be great !

Comment: subtraction ...

Comment: this will lead me to a 2 variables modular equation..

Comment: okay you can eventually solve it.

Comment: so why not directly solve the first row of my system ?

Comment: you can get x is even out of that part. the second part could be reduced to x+z= (7/11) mod 26. then plugged into the first to solve for z if you want.

Comment: I end up with ((cst -7z mod 26 )+ 8z ) mod 26 = 22, how do i solve this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66436/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-romain-b).